# Passing Class type to a Windows Forms constructor and having to cast it to a Class Pointer to use it

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, c++-cli

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional in C++ with Windows Form, I have a class that I have to pass to the other Form, so here is what I'm doing

> //FirstFile.cpp

```
Usuario user;
user.usuario = "test";
user.senha = "stackoverflow";
ChooseService cs(user);     
cs.ShowDialog();
```

> //SecondFile.cpp

```
public ref class ChooseService : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:

        Usuario* usuario;


        ChooseService(Usuario user)
        {


            usuario = user;         
            //I need to cast the Usuario into Usuario*, so I can use it in the class
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }
        /...
```

as I said in my comment, I need to cast "Usuario" into "Usuario*" so I can access in the class using "this", by the way I can't make this

> Usuario usuario;

instead of pointer, because windows forms doesn't allow you, you have to use pointer. so how do I do this? is there any trick?
I hope I was clear enough, Thanks!

Comment: `&user` yields a `Usuario*`, but then you'll just have a dangling pointer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the pointer from an object is easy:

```
Usuario user;
Usuario* pUser = &user;
```

But it might render the pointer invalid, because `user` is in automatic storage and might be destroyed before you're done using `pUser`.

I suggest you allocate `user` dynamically and modify the constructor of `ChooseService` to take a pointer:

```
Usuario* user = new Usuario;
user->usuario = "test";
user->senha = "stackoverflow";
ChooseService cs(user);


//...

ChooseService(Usuario* user) {...}
```

In your particular case, your variant would work because both objects have the same lifetime, but it's dangerous in the long run.

Comment: Luchian sublime explanation, thank you very much. I even added you on facebook cause of that, if you see a brazilian request on facebook you know it was me haha, good to have such great programmers around. I overreacted in my answer, but I hit my head on the wall the whole afternoon, so here we go.

Comment: @Grego : Make sure you actually `delete` that pointer somewhere sane, otherwise you've got a classic memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldnt cast, you just take the address

Comment: Taking the address of `user` would result in a dangling pointer after the constructor body exits. I.e., it would compile, but it wouldn't run.

Comment: I thought that was given, copy it and then take the address. Point was that he thought this was a type conversion using a cast where as it actually wasnt.

Comment: Copy it to where? A `ref class` cannot hold a native object by value. The fact that the argument is passed by value (and consequently making a copy) is the _problem_.